# Running command with string representing an alias won't recognise alias

Tags: bash, environment-variables, alias

I am trying to provide to a function a $@ containing commands where one of the words might be an alias. If one of the words is an alias, it won't be recognised.

Below is a minimal working example showing the issue I am having.

```
# Defining an alias
alias lsl="ls -l"

# Running with alias
lsl 2>&1 | tee test_out1.txt

# Running via variable (regular command)
export TEST_CMD_REGULAR="ls"
"$TEST_CMD_REGULAR" 2>&1 | tee test_out2.txt

# Running via variable (alias command)
export TEST_CMD_ALIAS="lsl"
"$TEST_CMD_ALIAS" 2>&1 | tee test_out3.txt
```

The first two commands will work, but the third won't recognise `lss`.

Comment: Can you not say: `$ export TEST_CMD_ALIAS="ls -l"`

Comment: Unfortunately the large script in which this example then goes requires as TEST_CMD_ALIAS an arbitrary input which _might_ contain an alias.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, thanks to a friend.
In my case application replacing `$TEST_CMD` with `eval $TEST_CMD` will work.

Comment: Shudder!!! `eval` is dangerous especially when you have little control over what is being `eval`'d. Take a look at [this](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'll try to think of something else.

Answer (score 0):

An alias also won't be recognized if you quote it; i.e., if you run `"lsl"` the alias isn't recognized. They are also not recognized when resulting from a var expansion. This is a fundamental limitation of aliases. From the bash man page:

```
The  first word of each simple command, if unquoted, is checked to see if it has an alias.
```

Also, aliases by default only work in interactive shells and aren't expanded by default in a script. You have to explicitly enable the feature via `shopt expand_aliases`. Which I strongly discourage you from doing.

Rather than an alias use a function:

```
$ function lsl() ( ls -l "$@" )
$ X="lsl x*"
$ $X
-rw-r-----  1 krader  staff  114 Nov  1 11:02 x.py
```